# Enable ANSI sequences in windows terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, lua, ansi-escape

I stumbled upon an interesting issue
in Windows:

```
C:\> lua
> print("\x1b[95mMagenta\x1b[0m")
-[95mMagenta-[0m
```

But if I run `os.execute()` even with an empty command,
before it, it works as expected:

```
C:\> lua
> os.system(""); print("\x1b[95mMagenta\x1b[0m")
Magenta
```

(the last line is printed with Magenta color)

[image: terminal screenshot]

Why it happens, and how can I make ANSI codes work
without calling `os.execute()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ANSI codes to work in a console, you should set specific `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` mode by invoking WinAPI function `SetConsoleMode`.

When you invoke `os.execute()` in Lua, Lua invokes C runtime function `system()`, which creates `cmd.exe` process, which initializes all the bells and whistles.
But Lua of course is unaware of Windows console features; it just works with a console having default settings.

---

**UPDATE:**
This is an example on how to turn ANSI escape sequences on from LuaJIT script:

```
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef[[
typedef int BOOL;
static const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE               = -1;
static const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE                  = -11;
static const int ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 4;
intptr_t GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
BOOL GetConsoleMode(intptr_t hConsoleHandle, int* lpMode);
BOOL SetConsoleMode(intptr_t hConsoleHandle, int dwMode);
]]
local console_handle = ffi.C.GetStdHandle(ffi.C.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
assert(console_handle ~= ffi.C.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
local prev_console_mode = ffi.new"int[1]"
assert(ffi.C.GetConsoleMode(console_handle, prev_console_mode) ~= 0, "This script must be run from a console application")
local function turn_VT(on_off)
   assert(ffi.C.SetConsoleMode(console_handle, bit.bor(prev_console_mode[0], on_off and ffi.C.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING or 0)) ~= 0)
end

print('\x1b[95mMagenta\x1b[m')
turn_VT(true)
print('\x1b[95mMagenta\x1b[m')
turn_VT(false)
print('\x1b[95mMagenta\x1b[m')
```

Comment: Yes, this sounds reasonable; you mean it changes the state of the current terminal, and even after the process is finished ther terminal has the changed state? And at the same time, this does not happen when cmd.exe is started on this terminal at first?

Comment: The mode of terminal is not a property of a terminal window.  It's a property of a console handle.  The parent (`cmd.exe`) and the child (`lua.exe`) processes access the same terminal window via different console handles. When `os.execute` creates the `cmd.exe` subprocess, the console handle is inherited by the child, this is the default behavior.  But when `cmd.exe` creates `lua.exe` subprocess, the console handle is not inherited, deliberately to isolate subprocesses from each other (your program does not depend on of the previous program run in the same console).

Comment: Yes, it seem to be exactly the case, but it is still not clear how it knows in what case a new console handle must be created and it what it must be inherited. Or cmd.exe creates a new console handle for each subprocess always?

Comment: `cmd.exe` deliberately prohibits console handle inheritance while creating subprocess. This is done by parameter `bInheritHandles` of WinAPI function `CreateProcessW()`

Comment: Any reason why this works on Lua 5.2+, but not Lua 5.1?

Comment: @Tieske - What code you are asking about?  The code in my answer requires LuaJIT, not Lua 5.x.

Comment: Both your code (the essence of it, I rewrote your code into a lib to test) and the original `os.execute("")`. Neither approach works with Lua 5.1, but they both worked with 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4.

Comment: Are there any differences on how you built Lua 5.1 vs Lua 5.2?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff finally figured it out; the sample code by the OP uses hex escape codes, `"\x1b"` which isn't supported on Lua 5.1. This works: `print("\027[95mMagenta\027[0m")` (using decimal escape codes)